# Create a connection to the mongodb if connection is not established

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to node.js and mongoose.

I am trying to check whether a database with supplied name exists or not,

if exists,
       establish a connection and use the same.

if not, 
     then create database with some collections.

I am using mongoose, as mongoose is providing 3 methods to establish the connection. i am unable to figure out which is the best suite for me and how to deal with them.

- connect
- createConnection
- connection

By googling i got succeed in figuring out whether the DB name exists or not using createConnection.

```
var Admin = mongoose.mongo.Admin;
var dbName='test';
        /// create a connection to the DB    
        var connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/' +dbName );
        connection.on('open', function () {
            // connection established
            new Admin(connection.db).listDatabases(function (err, result) {
                console.log('listDatabases succeeded');
                for (var i in result.databases) {
                    if (result.databases[i].name == dbName) {
                        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/' + dbName);
                        next();
                        break; 
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

I wrote the above code in route interceptor, so for every request the above code will be executed and trying to connect to mongodb if the given db name already exists.

Any help would be greatly appreciable..

Comment: MongoDB just creates database and collection namespaces "on the fly" anyway, so there is little need to write any code to do this. Your intent is not clear here as to why you would think you need to do this. But certainly it is not a good idea to intercept each call with an attempt to connect to a database. Database connections should be and are generally meant to persist for the lifecycle of your application. And that is also basically managed for you by mongoose.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Thank you for the response....can you please provie me a link which explains about those three functions in details and usage.

Comment: Well it's always worth reading the documentation on the [mongoose website](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) itself as well as the extensive [documention for MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/) if you are completely unfamilliar ( or even not completely familiar ). It's not clear from your question what you are really trying to do here. But it does suggest that you need to be more familiar with how MongoDB basically works as well as some core concepts of mongoose and mongoose models, as you do not appear to be familiar with by the tone here.